# PHP Environment variable

Tags: java, php, environment-variables

I am using [PHP Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)on a windows and linux server. Now I want to modify the 
CLASSPATH. When I do a phpinfo(), I see a CLASSPATH under environment variables section and 
when I output the `java.lang.system` properties there is a property called `java.class.path`.

First of all what is the difference between the two? How do I modify both of them? Can they be modified programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the phpinfo() information, but the System.property can't be set (to any effect) directly.  It is effectively read-only and taken from the environment CLASSPATH variable and -classpath command line option when Java is launched.

You can effectively change the classpath used to load classes by creating your own classloaders or class loader instances (see URLClassLoader) and using it to load from dynamic locations.